# I have a button that when I press it I want to subtract one from the number in front of it on the server side

Tags: php, html

I have a button when I press it. I want one to decrease from the number in front of it. I want it to decrease from the server side, not the client using php. How do I do that
html code

```
<div><p id="number_number" onclick="btn_number">number: 80</p></div>
<button name="button_click" id="button_click" onclick="btn_btn">click</button>
```

Comment: you have to share more code like how you are getting on server side

Comment: Sounds more like a job for Javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need some degree of JS for this, based on your sample html:

```
<?php
# Default number
$def = 80;
# Try and get the number
$i = ($_GET['i'])?? $def;
# See if it's numeric
if(is_numeric($i)) {
    // do whatever you are trying to do on the server to reduce the number.
    --$i;
}
else
    $i = $def;
?>

<div><p id="number_number" onclick="btn_number">number: 80</p></div>
<button name="button_click" id="button_click" onclick="setNumber()">click</button>

<script>
function setNumber()
{
    let number = document.getElementById('number_number');
    window.location = `?i=${number.innerText.replace(/[^\d]/gi,'')}`;
}
</script>
```

If you are echoing the number in the first place, you could just do an `<a>` tag with the value:

```
<?php
# Default number
$def = 80;
# Try and get the number
$i = ($_GET['i'])?? $def;
# See if it's numeric
if(is_numeric($i)) {
    // do whatever you are trying to do on the server to reduce the number.
    --$i;
}
else
    $i = $def;
?>

<a href="?i=<?php echo $i ?>">number: <?php echo $i ?></a>
```

Comment: @PishoyMoris Then you will have to explain more because the php portion is server-side. The JavaScript is client-side

Comment: @PishoyMoris not sure what you are looking for, what I have provided is the most I can do with the info you’ve given in your post.

Comment: @PishoyMoris The other answer is doing the same thing I am doing, just slightly different so we are both reading your post the same way, so you will need to clarify more in your post if you are looking for something different

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit weird to want to do it server side, but I guess you might have your reasons.

For starters you will need something to hold your value, I would use some sort of cookie or even `$_SESSION` for that, but lets try and minimize our code, so we will send the number to php every time the button is pressed.

Also since it has to be done in php, I'm thinking we should use a form to post the data. This means something like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['button_click'])){ //check if the form was submitted 
  $value = $_POST['value']-1; //subtract one from the submitted value
}else{
  $value = 80; //set the default value
}
?>
 <form method="post">
      <div><p id="number_number">number: <?=$value?></p>
           <input type="hidden" name="value" value="<?=$value?>" />
      </div>
      <button name="button_click" id="button_click">click</button>

 </form>
```

What this does is every time the button is pressed, it submits the value of the hidden input and then the new value will be decreased by one.

Just note that if you were using Javascript to change your value on the front end, you will also need to now change the value of the hidden input